# WKWebView snapshot not working after certain size

Tags: html, objective-c, wkwebview

I am using WKWebView in objective c to load my html string that i wrote for my project.

it actually worked and i managed to save the image in my image path BUT it didnt work if the height exceeds 4100.

Case A: html height < 4100

Case B: html height > 4100

i put my view off screen so people dont actually see it but its rendering in the "background", i got my height from the WKWebView using the javascript to capture my image.

this is my example code below,

getWKWebViewConfiguration --> settings

loadWebView --> a button to run my html string into wkWebview

```
+ (WKWebViewConfiguration *) getWKWebViewConfiguration
{
    NSString *jScript = @"var meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); meta.setAttribute('content', initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=yes'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);";
    WKUserScript *wkUScript = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource:jScript injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentEnd forMainFrameOnly:YES];
    WKUserContentController *wkUController = [[WKUserContentController alloc] init];
    [wkUController addUserScript:wkUScript];
    
    WKWebViewConfiguration *config = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
    if ([self deviceIsIOS10])
    {
        //these 2 only available since iOS10.
        config.dataDetectorTypes = NO;              
        config.ignoresViewportScaleLimits = NO;
    }
    config.userContentController = wkUController;
    
    return config;
}


- (void) loadWebView
{
    //x origin = 2000, to render off screen.
    view = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2000, 0, webviewWidth, webviewHeight) configuration:[self getWKWebViewConfiguration]];
    view.UIDelegate = self;
    view.navigationDelegate = self;
    [view loadHTMLString:reportString baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
}

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation {
    [webView evaluateJavaScript:@"document.body.offsetHeight" completionHandler:^(id result, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil) {
            float height = [result floatValue];
            WKSnapshotConfiguration *snapshotConfig = [[WKSnapshotConfiguration alloc] init];
            snapshotConfig.rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
            snapshotConfig.snapshotWidth = @(width);
            
            __block UIImage *testImage = nil;
            [webView takeSnapshotWithConfiguration:snapshotConfig completionHandler:^(UIImage * _Nullable snapshotImage, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                if (error == nil) {
                    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 1.0); 
                    [testImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
                    testImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
                    
                    [self saveImage:testImage];
                }
            }];
        }
    }];

}
```

testImage in both cases is NOT nil. but when i save testImage in Case A, it will show exactly what i wrote for html but in Case B, it will just show an empty white background with the height assigned.

Appreciate if anyone could help. Thanks in advance!

I've tried converting UIImage to NSData and writeToFile but it still shows empty. Possible due to the UIImage is empty from the start.

Tried to run the wkwebview on screen where i could see it in my view. both cases show the html string and rendered. however, only case B couldn't do the snapshot and save it as a image in my path.